# Process Start ("Μy website") does not support over a number of characters

Tags: c#

I'm using this code for opening a browser with a url inside.Cause my app uses smtp server for senting sms,i'm creating a stringbuilder with all my mobile phones. So if my url its over e.x 2000 characters.My browser opens but my url it is not complete.On the other method,if i will get my url as string and copy-paste into my browser it works fine.

```
 Process.Start("MyWebsite/mobiles="+richTextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide path of the browser by first string and arguments by the second string as it is described by MSDN [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Start(String, String)  Starts a process resource by specifying the
>   name of an application and a set of command-line arguments, and
>   associates the resource with a new Process component.